# Why can't I get a output lower than 0V in this diode and capacitor circuit?

Tags: capacitor, diodes, modeling

[image]

In the image above green is my input (node left side capacitor) and blue is my output (node right side of the capacitor).
I would expect that the blue signal would follow the input, but it does not do this. Why is this the case? Can you explain this with open circuit and short circuit equivalents for the diode?

Comment: Because it is supposed to do that. The circuit shown in your question is called a [clamper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamper_%28electronics%29) circuit.

Comment: I told you to clean up the ambiguities and messiness in the identical question you posted on Physics.SE.  There is no excuse for dumping the same stuff on us, especially after having been told of the problems.  Cross-posting is also not appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a step by step list of what happens:

- The input starts positive. The diode is reverse biased, so no current flows and the capacitor doesn't charge.
- Around \$t = 0.5s\$, the input becomes negative. The diode is forward biased, so the capacitor charges to \$1 V\$ (the negative of the minimum voltage applied). Note that there is no resistor, so there is no time constant - the capactor acts like an open circuit (as if the source is DC).
- After the capacitor finishes charging, there is an offset of \$+1 V\$, and the diode never becomes forward biased again. The output is \$V_{in} + 1V\$.

Comment: Thanks. Why is the forward bias at t=0.5s and not directly after the peak value (t=0.25s) for the capacitor when $C*dv/dt$ is negative? What happens at t=0.75s? Does the diode acts as an open circuit circuit and it stays an open circuit?

Comment: The voltage at 0.25s is all dropped across the diode, not the capacitor, so dV/dt is 0. You're correct about the open circuit diode.

Answer (score 1):

Kynit's answer is correct, but I think what makes this circuit confusing is the location of the ground node. Let's pick a different node and see what happens.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fguvb1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here's a simulation. Download the image or open it in a separate tab to see the full-size version. V(Old_right_node) - V(Old_ground) is your output voltage. V(Old_ground) is the negative of your input voltage.

[image: Simulation with ground moved to the other side of the voltage source]

Now you can see what's going on. For the first half-cycle, the diode is off. The capacitor is uncharged, so the voltage across it is zero. This causes your input to follow your output. During the second half-cycle, the diode conducts, charging the capacitor to 1V. There's no voltage across the diode, so your output is clamped to your ground.

Once the capacitor is charged, the diode never turns on again. V1 can't produce more than 1V, so V(Old_ground) can never be greater than V(Old_right_node). The voltage between your output and input is equal to the capacitor voltage, which is a constant 1V. In your circuit, V1 varies your input voltage. In my circuit, V1 varies your ground voltage. Either way, the result is the same. It's just a question of which reference point you use.

Answer (score 1):

That diode model you're using is totally unrealistic. You should get a shifted sine wave that goes negative by somewhat less than a volt and (very slowly) rises as time goes on. Something like this (1N4004 model):

[image]

Eventually (after a *very* long time) it will resemble your curve, but it will take a very long time because the diode does not conduct much current at lower voltages and it has to charge a 1 Farad capacitor.

Comment: Could you explain why you have this difference between an ideal diode and a non-ideal diode like the 1N4004?

Comment: The 1N4004 does not begin to conduct much current until the forward voltage is 600mV or so. To charge the 1F cap quickly requires a lot of current. Your ideal diode will conduct any amount of current once forward biased even a tiny amount.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, you could estimate this with a diode's "on" resistance - when the diode conducts, the capacitor charges as if it's part of an RC connection.

Comment: With cap connected directly to -1V just after turn-on, the voltage is still at -320mV (still rather far from zero) after two hours. Reduce the cap to 1000uF and it gets to -7.6mV in two hours.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit given in the question is a positive clamper.

Figure below shows a diode clamper that inserts a positive dc level in the output waveform. The operation of this circuit can be seen by considering the first negative half-cycle of the input voltage.

When the input voltage initially goes negative, the diode is forward biased, allowing
the capacitor to charge to near peak of the input(\$V_p(in) - 0.7 V\$), as shown in figure.

*(It can take many negative cycles to get the capacitor charged to the peak. It depends on the value of capacitor, forward resistance of diode and amplitude of voltage source.)*

Just after the capacitor getting charged to negative peak, the diode is reverse biased. This is because the cathode is held near \$V_p(in) - 0.7 V\$ by the charge on the capacitor. Assume it is \$R_L = \infty\$ and hence capacitor does not have a discharge path.

[image]

So once the capacitor is charged to peak, the diode is reverse biased and The capacitor voltage acts essentially as a battery in series with the input voltage The dc voltage of the capacitor adds to the input voltage by superposition as in figure (b). So the output voltage will be

$$V_o = V_{in} + V_c = V_{in} + V_p(in) - 0.7 $$

That is why you are not getting negative voltages.